# SSRS: Auto Refresh on Parameter selection

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have two parameter values for two different reports. If ParameterValue1 gets selected the "Report1" gets displayed and similarly for parameterValue2.

ParameterValue1 is the default i.e. Report1 gets displayed by default.

Requirement: If I am selecting parameterValue2, It should display the "Report2" without clicking the "View report" button. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. However, you can press ENTER instead of clicking the view report button.